# Display menu item label with subscript (or supscript) style

Tags: javascript, node.js, unicode, electron

In electron, the app menu is defined:

```
const menuTemplate = [
    {
      label:"Menu Item 1",
      click(){
        //define some behaviour
      }
    }
];
```

Is there some way to display the menu item name as `Menu Item ₁`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to answer your question, which somehow lacks details and clarity...

1/ If you want to display the menu item name as `Menu Item ₁`, just use that string in the menu template:

```
const menuTemplate = [
    {
      label:"Menu Item ₁",
      click(){
        //define some behaviour
      }
    }
];
```

2/ If you're asking whether it's possible to make use of markup tags such as HTML's `<sub>` and `<sup>` in menu items, I'm afraid the answer is *no*. AFAIK, menus are handled at the OS level and no specific styling is available...

3/ If what you have in mind is to programmatically convert digits 0 to 9 to their Unicode subscript and superscript counterparts, then this can be done independently of menus, by simple string manipulation:

```js
function toSub (string)
{
    const subscriptDigits = "₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉";   // "\u2080\u2081\u2082\u2083\u2084\u2085\u2086\u2087\u2088\u2089"
    return string.replace (/(\d)/g, digit => subscriptDigits[digit]);
}
function toSuper (string)
{
    const superscriptDigits = "⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹";   // "\u2070\u00B9\u00B2\u00B3\u2074\u2075\u2076\u2077\u2078\u2079"
    return string.replace (/(\d)/g, digit => superscriptDigits[digit]);
}
console.log (toSub ("Menu Item 1"));
console.log (toSuper ("Menu Item 1"));
```